# Number of contextBridge in electron preload.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron

To provide suitable levels of security when loading remote content, it is stated that a `BrowserWindow`'s `contextIsolation` and `nodeIntegration` options must be enabled and disabled respectively. In this scenario, Node/Electron APIs will not be available to the main renderer process. In order to expose specific functionality, the window's preload script may exploit Electron's `contextBridge` feature, providing the main renderer with access to selected Node/Electron APIs.

[Here](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) is the single contextBridge usage example I've managed to find online but it only contains one `contextBridge`.

I understand how to use `contextBridge` my question is, Is there a limit to how many `contextBridge`s i can use in one `preload.js` file and if I can use multiple contextBridges then what do you suggest I should use a template folder structure to import them into one `preload.js`

Comment: why do you need multiple `contextBridge`s? Just for the sake of using different api keys?

Comment: Yeah to separate the keys and have many smaller contextBridges than one large object @pushkin

Comment: For the keys, sure. Regarding the point about smaller objects, you can just create how ever many objects you want and then using a single contextBridge, pass in `Object.assign(obj1, obj2, obj3)` to combine them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple `contextBridge`s. As for the folder structure, that's really up to you and depends on the nature of the project (like whether you're sharing some APIs between different preloads).